# when i use input line and start without debuging app just crash

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013

hi all im new so go easy on me

im using c right know
when im trying to use any kind of input line then when i start the app when it get to the input its just crashes

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Pick a number\n");
        scanf("%d, &number");
    printf("you enterd the number: %d, &number");
    return 0;
}
```

at the point i need to press a number i do soo and then boom crash!

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%d, &number");` --> `scanf("%d", &number);` , `printf("you enterd the number: %d, &number");` --> `printf("you enterd the number: %d\n", number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all wrong. I suggest you lookup into the basics of C first. Anyway, this is how it's supposed to be done:

```
int number;
printf("Pick a number\n");
scanf("%d", &number);
printf("you enterd the number: %d", number);
return 0;
```